# in flutter dart convert 1624275605667 into Mon Jun 21 2021 17:10:05 GMT+05:30

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

```
var date = 1624275605667;
        final DateTime formatted = DateTime(date);
        final DateFormat fr = DateFormat('EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss');
        final String dd = fr.format(formatted);
```

I try like this but getting some type of errors.

I want to convert 1624275605667 into this format Mon Jun 21 2021 17:10:05 GMT+05:30

For this which format I use here

```
DateFormat('EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz')
```

Comment: I see two issues here. First one is incorrect DateTime construction. You should rather use  DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch constructor. Second is that you are trying to format timezone ('zzz' part), which is not supported by DateFormat. I guess if it is critical for you to have time zone offset part in the string, you should format it yourself based on timeZoneOffset info of datetime.

Comment: Alex Radzishevsky -   GMT+05:30 how i get this in my result

Comment: formatted.timeZoneOffset will return tz offset duration. You can then use it to format "GMT+05:30" manually.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one

```
var date = 1624275605667;
    final DateTime formatted = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(date);
    final DateFormat fr = DateFormat('EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    final String dd = fr.format(formatted);
    print(dd);
```

You are using `z` pattern and it's not implemented yet. Issue is still open since 2015 https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/19

And in [intl package](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) already mentioned that this characters are reserved and currently are unimplemented.

For workaround you can use

```
formatted.timeZoneOffset.toString(); /// 5:30:00.000000
```

Which is same as `GMT+05:30`

Comment: Thankyou Hemal for your precious time ......    Actually i need GMT+05:30  in my time format result.      How i get??

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please take a look.